# Integrity comparison for increasing number

Tags: algorithm

The server continuously generates increasing numbers (not guaranteed to be continuous) and constantly sent these numbers to the client by different http packets. and packets may be lost(the server won't store the status of whether the number is sent successfully). for example:

> numbers from server：1, 3, 5, 8, 14, **<18>**, 23, 34, 56 ......
>
> numbers client maybe received: 1, 3, 5, 8, 14, **<>**, 23, 34, 56 ......

Now the client wants to determine if the sequence of numbers in a certain range is consistent with the server. for example, the client wanna find the number of 18 lost. How to complete this process with the minimum amount of data.

for example, the client request server with start_num=3, end_num=34, and the server response client with all the numbers between 3 and 34. then the client could compare them and find 18 lost. However, this method requires too much data to be transmitted. Is there a better algorithm or method for Less redundancy like Hamming code for error correction?

what if the increasing numbers are continuously？

Comment: I don't think the HTTP packets can be lost.

Comment: What about returning the number of numbers in the queried range ?

Comment: returning the count of numbers could help to find if there are numbers lost, couldn't help to find which number lost

Comment: Any reason you can't simply transmit a continuous sequence with the increasing sequence as a pair? {s=1, v=1}, {s=2, v=3}, {s=3, v=5}, ...? Then the client can easily see which values it didn't get and request them again.

Comment: Take a look at Reed Solomon error detection and correction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction

Answer (score 0):

Do xor of arrays:

```
public static void findMissingNumber() {
        int[] numbersFromServer = {1, 3, 5, 8, 14, 18, 23, 34, 56};
        int[] numberClientReceived = {1, 3, 5, 8, 14, 23, 34, 56};
        int xor = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbersFromServer.length; i++) {
            xor ^= numbersFromServer[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numberClientReceived.length; i++) {
            xor ^= numberClientReceived[i];
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Missing number: %s", xor));
    }
```

This is `O(n)` and don't need additional space.
Also notice that it works because `1^1 = 0`. The same numbers give `0` while xoring and only the missing one will not xor with anything.

What do you exacly mean by

> what if the increasing numbers are continuously？

it's `1,2,3,4...` and one is missing? Then you can count the sum of full array `(n*(n+1)/2)` and substract sum of the array with missing number.

Comment: If I'm reading the assignment correctly, the client has a list of numbers received from the server but doesn't have the list of numbers sent by the server.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis I think you are right, seems my answer can be thrown to trash

Comment: If it's the real problem then server must communicate with client by TCP protocol which ensure that nothing is lost.

Comment: TCP is not and cannot be guaranteed to be loss-and-error-free. There's a messy real world out there. What happens if a guy with a backhoe cuts the one network line leading into a building, resulting in all connections being immediately and irreparably severed? What it *does* guarantee is "the network", meaning all the intermediate nodes on the network, will **attempt** to route around a network break, that packets will appear to the client to be received in the order they were sent, and in the event that data *is* lost the client will receive an indication of that data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Send the "next" number in the sequence, and the delta from the previous number. This would look something like:

```
Received from server
Current number   Delta from previous
1                0
3                2
5                2
8                3
14               6
23               5
34               11
56               22
```

To determine if a number is missing, as is the case here, the receiver sums the previous number and the delta. If the sum is not equal to the currently received number it indicates a missing number. Thus:

```
Received from server
Current number   Delta from previous  Delta + previous
1                0                     0 delta = first number received
3                2                     2 +  1 = 3  : OK
5                2                     2 +  3 = 5  : OK
8                3                     3 +  5 = 8  : OK
14               6                     6 +  8 = 14 : OK
23               5                     5 + 14 = 19 : ERROR
34               11                   11 + 23 = 34 : OK
56               22                   22 + 34 = 56 : OK
```

The client can also attempt to use the delta to rebuild the list. In the case of a single missing number, the "missing" number can be reconstructed from the number received minus the delta received. In our error case here, 23 - 5 = 18.

If you can stand a little more overhead, the server can generate numbers one "ahead", so it can send both forward and backward deltas. In this manner the client can verify that it received the correct number, can recover reliably from the loss of a single number, and detect if multiple numbers have been missed. This would look something like:

```
Received from server
                                                                       Expected # =
Current number   Back delta   Forward delta   Back delta + previous    Current + fwd delta
1                0            2                0 delta = first # rcvd  1 + 2 = 3
3                2            2                2 +  1 = 3  : OK        3 + 2 = 5
5                2            3                2 +  3 = 5  : OK        5 + 3 = 8
8                3            6                3 +  5 = 8  : OK        8 + 6 = 14
14               6            4                6 +  8 = 14 : OK        14 + 4 = 18
23               5           11                5 + 14 = 19 : ERROR     23 + 11 = 34
34               11          22               11 + 23 = 34 : OK        34 + 22 = 56
56               22          ...              22 + 34 = 56 : OK        ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually, your answer could be translated into this. when sending the current number, carry the previous number by the way. this could solve the situation of there is at most one number lost between two numbers.  the fact is that there could be several numbers lost between any two numbers